# Low pass filter

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

currently I'm using AVAudioEngine to get audio samples from a microphone and successfully implemented FFT.
For stable frequency values, I've also implemented a Hann window on audio samples before FFT.
now I wanted to implement Low pass filter on audio samples to eliminate high frequencies.
I did some research regarding low pass filter in iOS but most of the answers found with AVAudioUnit.
It confuses me, is it possible to implement a low pass filter in AVAudioEngine only?
It is possible to apply a low pass filter on audio samples?
If yes, which approach do we need to follow?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the poorly documented world of AVAudioEngine.

Not sure how you have setup your AVAudioEngine, but as a quick run through I am guessing you will be looking at something a long these lines:

Create the engine `let engine = AVAudioEngine()`
Create effect node `var equalizer = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 1)`
Attach the nodes `engine.attach(equalizer)`
Connect the node `engine.connect(equalizer, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFormat)`
Prepare and start the engine. `engine.prepare();try engine.start();`
You will also have attached and connected a playerNode for your audio samples.

As for your question. The AVAudioUnits are subclasses that your effect nodes use to let AVAudioEngine manipulate the audio. You use these indirectly with the AVAudioEngine through the nodes you manipulate.

In order to let the AVAudioEngine manipulate the lowpass filter you could instantiate an `AVAudioUnitEQ` with one band (as above). And then manipulate the effect with a function that shifts the frequency of the filter:

```
    func setLowPassFilter(frequency: Float){
        filter.bands[0].filterType = .lowPass
        filter.bands[0].frequency = frequency
        filter.bands[0].bypass = false
    }
```

Key with these AVAudioUnitEQ effects is to set bypass = false, otherwise it will ignore your effect.

I hope this helps. The AVAudioEngine world is quite lonely, so I would like to point you to this free app: [Phonique](https://apps.apple.com/nl/app/phonique/id909884542?l=en&mt=12)

This is an app created by a real AudioEngine pro - Chris Davis - and allows you to easily experiment with the AVAudioEngine to find your effects and then check his cleanly generated code for how it is wired up. In [this](https://medium.com/@nthState/phonique-avaudioengine-936058e6bd9f) post he explains how it works. It doesn't always offer a drop in replacement for your own code, but it is the perfect place to see how things should be wired up. Good luck

Comment: I have a similar problem, even though attaching equalizer it seems like it does not have any effect . I have posted question here, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382340/low-pass-filter-sample-rate-conversion-using-avaudioengine-ios