# iOS: Apply audio modifications to Music library content

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm working on an iOS/[Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) application, and am trying to work out if it's possible to play audio from the Music library on iOS with audio modifications (e. g. equalization settings) applied.

It seems like I'm looking for a solution that can work with [MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller#topics), since that appears to be the strategy for playing local audio from the user's iOS Music library. I can find examples of applying EQ to audio on iOS (e. g. using AVAudioUnitEQ and AVAudioEngine: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409092/low-pass-filter), [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21672160-avaudioengine-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)), but I'm unable to find any resources to help me understand if it's possible to bridge the gap between these resources.

*Flutter specific context:*

There are Flutter plugins that provide some of the functionality I'm looking for, but don't appear to work together. For example, the [just_audio plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) has a robust set of features for modifying audio, but [does not work with the local Music application on iOS/MPMusicPlayerController](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/338). Other plugins that do work with MPMusicPlayerController, like [playify](https://pub.dev/packages/playify), do not have the ability to modify/transform the audio.

Even though I'm working with Flutter, any general advice on the iOS side would be very helpful. I appreciate any insight someone with more knowledge may be able to share with me!

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller#topics) it doesn't appear to expose anything useful for modification (eg an audio stream of some sort). Perhaps someone else will have an idea, but it doesn't seem promising based on the documented properties.

Comment: Thanks for giving this a look @jnpdx! Agreed, just seems strange because there are plenty of equalizer iOS apps that appear to work with a user's Music library. Wondering if there's some alternative to MPMusicPlayerController entirely that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating with my own answer here for future people: It looks like my only path forward (for now) is leaning into into [AVAudioEngine](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-control-the-pitch-and-speed-of-audio-using-avaudioengine) directly. This is the rough POC that worked for me:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
var eq = AVAudioUnitEQ()

let mediaItemCollection: [MPMediaItem] = MPMediaQuery.songs().items!
let song = mediaItemCollection[0]
    
do {
  let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: song.assetURL!)
  audioEngine.attach(audioPlayer)
  audioEngine.attach(eq)
  audioEngine.connect(audioPlayer, to: eq, format: nil)
  audioEngine.connect(eq, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: file.processingFormat)
  audioPlayer.scheduleFile(file, at: nil)
  try audioEngine.start()
  audioPlayer.play()
} catch {
  // catch
}
```

The trickiest part for me was working out how to bridge together the "Music library/MPMediaItem" world to "AVAudioEngine" world -- which was just `AVAudioFile(forReading: song.assetURL!)`