# Low Pass filter + sample rate conversion using Avaudioengine iOS

Tags: swift, frequency, avaudioengine, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

We are working on a project which allows us to record some sounds from a microphone with a 5k Hz sample rate with some Low-Pass filter & HighPass filter.

**What we are using**

We are using **AvaudioEngine** for this purpose.

We are using **AVAudioConverter** for downgrading the sample rate.

We are using **AVAudioUnitEQ** for the LowPass & HighPass filter.

**Code**

```
let bus = 0
let inputNode = engine.inputNode

let equalizer = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 2)

equalizer.bands[0].filterType = .lowPass
equalizer.bands[0].frequency = 3000
equalizer.bands[0].bypass = false

equalizer.bands[1].filterType = .highPass
equalizer.bands[1].frequency = 1000
equalizer.bands[1].bypass = false
engine.attach(equalizer) //Attach equalizer

// Connect nodes
engine.connect(inputNode, to: equalizer, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
engine.connect(equalizer, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
engine.connect(engine.mainMixerNode, to: engine.outputNode, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))

let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16,
                                            sampleRate: 5000,
                                            channels: 1,
                                            interleaved: false)!

// Converter to downgrade sample rate
guard let converter: AVAudioConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0), to: outputFormat) else {
           print("Can't convert in to this format")
           return
       }

engine.mainMixerNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 2688, format: engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)) { (buffer, time) in
           
     var newBufferAvailable = true
           
     let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
           if newBufferAvailable {
                outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                newBufferAvailable = false
                return buffer
           } else {
                outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                return nil
           }
     }
           
           
     let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!

           var error: NSError?
           let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
           assert(status != .error)

           
           if status == .haveData {
             // Process with converted buffer
           }
            
       }
       
       engine.prepare()
       
       do {
           try engine.start()
       } catch {
           print("Can't start the engine: \(error)")
       }
```

**Issue**

low-pass and high-pass filters are not working.

**Alternate Approach**

To check code is working or not, we have added a reverb effect instead of lowpass filter.
Reverb effect(Using **AVAudioUnitReverb**) works with same code.

Can anyone help me where are we doing wrong in applying lowpass filter?

Comment: @sbooth I have tried with that but the result is the same. No effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main problem with this code was that the `AVAudioConverter` was being created before calling `engine.prepare()` which can and will change the `mainMixerNode` output format. Aside from that, there was a redundant connection of `mainMixerNode` to `outputNode`, along with a probably incorrect format - `mainMixerNode` is documented to be automatically created and connected to the output node "on demand". The tap also did not need a format.

```
let bus = 0
let inputNode = engine.inputNode

let equalizer = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 2)

equalizer.bands[0].filterType = .lowPass
equalizer.bands[0].frequency = 3000
equalizer.bands[0].bypass = false

equalizer.bands[1].filterType = .highPass
equalizer.bands[1].frequency = 1000
equalizer.bands[1].bypass = false
engine.attach(equalizer) //Attach equalizer

// Connect nodes
engine.connect(inputNode, to: equalizer, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
engine.connect(equalizer, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))

// call before creating converter because this changes the mainMixer's output format
engine.prepare()

let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16,
                                 sampleRate: 5000,
                                 channels: 1,
                                 interleaved: false)!

// Downsampling converter
guard let converter: AVAudioConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0), to: outputFormat) else {
    print("Can't convert in to this format")
    return
}

engine.mainMixerNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 2688, format: nil) { (buffer, time) in
    var newBufferAvailable = true
    
    let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
        if newBufferAvailable {
            outStatus.pointee = .haveData
            newBufferAvailable = false
            return buffer
        } else {
            outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    
    let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!
    
    var error: NSError?
    let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
    assert(status != .error)
    
    
    if status == .haveData {
        // Process with converted buffer
    }
}

do {
    try engine.start()
} catch {
    print("Can't start the engine: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I never thought allocating objects will cause the issue. It saves my day. :) Also I have one question what will be the best minimum value for the low pass filter? When I check the frequency parameter, there is something written like (Samplerate / 2). Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea - sorry.

Comment: Okay thank you the help.

Comment: When you downsample a signal, any frequencies in the signal that are above `samplerate/2` Hz (where `samplerate` is the new, lower samplerate) will show up in your downsampled signal as low frequencies (this is called aliasing). This is why low-pass filtering is a necessary pre-processing step for downsampling. The highest value for the low-pass cutoff-frequency that avoids aliasing is therefore `samplerate/2` (the Nyquist frequency). But given that filters are never perfect, your best bet is to choose it a bit lower than `samplerate/2`.

Comment: Hello @BhavinVaghela I am not able to apply low pass and high pass filter with avaudio engine. here is a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762443/avaudioengine-adding-low-pass-filter-on-a-song-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    lableItem.text = "Select Frequency"
    setUpDropdown()
    navigationItem.title = "High Pass Filter"
    
    do{
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .defaultToSpeaker,.allowBluetoothA2DP,.allowAirPlay,.allowBluetooth])
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    let bus = 0
    let inputNode = engine.inputNode
    
    let equalizer = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 2)
    
    equalizer.bands[0].filterType = .highPass
    equalizer.bands[0].frequency = 20000.0
    equalizer.bands[0].bypass = false
    
    equalizer.bands[1].filterType = .lowPass
    equalizer.bands[1].frequency = 1000.0
    equalizer.bands[1].bypass = false
    engine.attach(equalizer) //Attach equalizer
    
    
    // Connect nodes
    engine.connect(inputNode, to: equalizer, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
    engine.connect(equalizer, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
    
    // call before creating converter because this changes the mainMixer's output format
    engine.prepare()
    
    let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt32,
                                     sampleRate: 44100,
                                     channels: 1,
                                     interleaved: false)!
    // Downsampling converter
    guard let converter: AVAudioConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0), to: outputFormat) else {
        print("Can't convert in to this format")
        return
    }
    
    engine.mainMixerNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 2688, format: nil) { (buffer, time) in
        var newBufferAvailable = true
        
        let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
            if newBufferAvailable {
                outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                newBufferAvailable = false
                
                return buffer
            } else {
                outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        
        let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!
        
        var error: NSError?
        let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
        assert(status != .error)
        
        
        if status == .haveData {
            // Process with converted buffer
        }
    }
    
    do {
        try engine.start()
    } catch {
        print("Can't start the engine: \(error)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 1) I have added you code  right now  there is no effect when we take the input from the microphone.                
2)My goal is I want the frequency about 20k suppress output and after that I want to apply high pass filter with 1000 lowPass filter 
3 )When I run this code I am getting the error that when we put 25k there is no effect

Comment: I think you misinterpreted HighPass and low pass, you should interchange the value and it should work.